# Estimate final size of image without writing it to disk with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Assume I generate a PNG image with `matplotlib`. The parameters that determine the image's size and DPI (`x_size, y_size, dpi_val`) are set by me (see MWE below)

Is there a way to at least approximate the size that the image file will have once it's created, *without writing the file to disk*?

---

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Figure parameters.
x_size, y_size, dpi_val = 10, 15, 300

x, y = np.random.uniform(0., 10., 100), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 100)
plt.figure(figsize=(x_size, y_size))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=dpi_val)
```

Comment: Do you mean without generating it or without writing it to disk? These might be two different things.

Comment: jure the question said "*writing the file to disk*", I just modified the title to say the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to (untested, but from reading the docs) pass a file-like object instead of a file name. Such an object is a `StringIO` object, whose length you can check after "writing" the file.

```
import StringIO
f = StringIO.StringIO()
plt.savefig(f, ...)
size = len(f.getvalue())
```

A file-like object is anything with the same API as a file, so you could also (again untested) define a class with a `write` method that just counts its input.

```
class Buffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
    def write(self, bytes):
        self.size += len(bytes)

f = Buffer()
plt.savefig(f, ...)
size = f.size
```

(Which methods you define for `Buffer` depends on what `savefig` actually tries to call; I omitted the ones I assume aren't used.)

Comment: a quick test of the two methods: the first doesn't seem to work (I get size = 0), but the second method does work (I get ~ 150KB for both the Buffer and the actual png created in the OP's question)

Comment: Getting the size from the `StringIO` method can work, with a small change: use `import os; f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END); size = f.tell()` instead of `size=len(f.read())`

Comment: `size = len(f.getvalue())` should also work for the `StringIO` object. I'm surprised; if I'd had to bet on which of my two untested attempts would have worked, I'd have bet on `StringIO`.

Comment: Ah. `size = len(f.getvalue())` does work. `size=len(f.read())` does not. :)

Comment: So neither method depends on what I actually put inside the image? Somehow I thought that would influence the final size. BTW: great answer @chepner, thank you! And thank you tom too for checking both methods.

Comment: Yeah, `read` just seemed like the obvious choice from a quick glance of the docs. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, even after calling `f.flush()`. Oh well, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, what you put in the image *will* influence the final size. These methods tell you, after you have done all your plotting, how large that file will be when you want to save it to disk

Comment: You are correct @tom. Don't know why I assumed that leaving out `plt.scatter(...)` would have no influence.